# multiple python scripts one text file

Tags: python, filesystems

I want to know if it can be done.

I have a script made in python that takes a random line from a text file, process it and returns a modified line, i insert it in the file and that's it.

My problem is that i want to expand the script, make it multithreading, is there a chance that the script wont be accurate in writing the line to the text file, i mean the script runs fast and i don't know if the file system will crash or not, has anyone used text files for this kind of thing, what would you recommend instead of text files?

If i move all the data to a database mysql/sql(whatever) will i loose from the speed much? I mean reading a text file is done quite quick, if i connect to the database and get the data after that process it, it takes time i presume, or wont it if i install a mysql server on my pc..?

Please keep in mind that the file is growing extremely fast extremely big.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How big of a file are you talking about? You said it's growing quickly. The nice thing about putting something in a db like postgres is write-ahead logging. There are several nice python libraries for interacting with db's like psycopg2 for postgres. Do you have a need to query information in the future, in which case a db may be worth any minor loss in speed.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write-ahead_logging

http://initd.org/psycopg/

Comment: tens of gigs... hundreds maybe, i can't really select from it and delete cause that data is used for further processing, in other words i need it all. I am afraid that the file system will crash if i use it continuously in a hardcore mode to put it like that.

Comment: I would go for a database that many lines, I would bet money it would take up less space and the perform well. Write ahead logs can save your butt if the server crashes in the middle of your script writing to the db, versus writing to a text file which would have no protection at all.

Comment: Thank you for your interest and time, i will go for mysql.